Are all types of noise a result of lack of complete knowledge about the given system? What does this say about the physicality about information?
I am currently studying the basics of quantum information theory. When we study a system (classical or quantum), any undesirable influence out of our control is usually referred to as noise, and this is the definition I've been learning since high school. I've just taken this definition at face value for years, but now, to come and think of it, are all noises just an outcome of a lack of complete information (theoretically speaking) about our system? My argument is that if we indeed had complete knowledge of the system, we wouldn't really have any of those "undesirable influences out of our control" because, in theory, we could include the 'noise' sources into our model as certainties and not uncertainties, if you get what I mean.  The only exceptions I could find for this are quantum noises resulting from the uncertainty principle, maximally mixed state behaviour of local states in an entangled state, and the quantum measurement principle.
I had this idea that there was something very physical about density operator formalism and the idea of quantum channels, and now it just seems like these are just models to tackle quantum systems with users having incomplete knowledge about the system. How 'physical' is the idea of information? It seems to me that the types of correlations you possess depend on the amount of information you have, and one can do physically meaningful things with such correlations, which means there indeed is something very 'physical' about information. For example, the entanglement of entropy is defined as $S_E = -Tr(\rho \log(\rho))$ where $\rho$ is a reduced density operator, and clearly, this is maximum if $\rho$ is maximally mixed, so the amount of correlation we have seems to increase as know lesser about a given system. Why should nature care about how much information I possess?
I seem rather very confused with this, so please bear with me if my question sounds unclear.

In classical communications systems, people usually make a distinction between noise, which comes from unwanted courses, and distortions, which are unwanted effects in the system that distort the information. While noise represents addition radiation or energy that overlaps the desired signal in configuration space and in the Fourier domain, the distortions are applied to the desired signal itself. Even if the system is completely known, these distortions can still destroy information if the process is not invertible. Noise is not known in principle, so it has nothing to do with the knowledge of the system. Although these concepts come from classical systems, they obviously also apply to quantum systems. But in the latter one also gets shot noise, which is intrinsic to the quantum nature of the field that carries the information.
